# How to determine the scene is dark by opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

There are many photos are dark, These photos does not make sense to the viewer.
So I want to use opencv identified it, how to do that by opencv?

Any python source example will good:)

[image: dark scene]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can transform the image to the HSV color space and use the V values for measuring the amount of light in the scene. Extract a histogram of the V values and compare it between light and dark images to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

your question is a little unclear as of what you wish to do. Can you give an example of the scene? I wish to see how dark it is before coming to a clear conclusion.

But if you just want to determine if an image is dark as via your title, its simple, draw an Histogram. Dark images tends to have peaks on the left hand side of the histogram, where the intensity of the pixels are pretty much in the value range of 0 to 20 or maybe can go up to 40/50, the right hand side of the histogram should pretty much have nothing should the image is really dark as what you mentioned. Following which, do a threshold on the image to determine whether the image is dark or not.

If you want to make the image clearer to the human eye, you can do histogram normalization. But that depends on how bad the image really is.

Was that what you are looking for?